# Finding and Replacing values in an XML

Tags: python, xml, replace, find

[Error and code pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqqyE.png)

I'm an amatuer coder, but I'm trying to write a code at work that will quickly replace all values in an XML. I want to replace every instance of 'linear' and 'angular' with a uniform value. I saved both the code and the XML to my desktop, and ran the code but I am coming up with the error pictured above. My code is also in the screenshot. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please copy and paste both the error and code to the question itself as a text instead of linking to the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend to post the code and error message below your question, as well as modify you code to give a working example!

Nonetheless, I think you have mistaken the *ElementTree.parse* method for *ElementTree.fromstring*. The first one parses the XML file given the file name to the function, the latter one parses the given string containing XML. To show the difference:

```
MyFile.xml:
<body>
  <linear>10</linear>
  <angular>0.314159</angular>
</body>

--------------------------------

from xml.etree import ElementTree

file_name = r'MyFile.xml'
et_parse = ElementTree.parse(file_name).get_root()

with open(file_name, 'r') as fid:
  file_content = fid.read()
et_fromstring = ElementTree.fromstring(file_content)

et_parse == et_fromstring
```

If you read the documentation of [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) carefully, you will find the difference of those methods mentioned within the first lines.